# mail() warning SMTP server response 501 Domain name required

Tags: php, email, warnings

I can't find a solution here.

The send form is working when i try it on my own domain but now it's on the domain of my 'customer'

Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 501 5.5.2 ... Domain name required in \192.168.0.100\LOCALUSER\woonkans\Test\verzonden.php on line 129

Simply this is the php code in the if(isset).

```
$to = "broowser@gmail.com";
$subject = "Mail via website, afzender: $name $lastname";
$from = "$name $lastname";
$message = "Van: $from \r\n Woonplaats $woonplaats \r\n \r\n BERICHT: \r\n  $message      \r\n \r\n E-mail: $email \r\n Telefoon:  $telephone";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);    //line 129
```

Does someone know where my issue could be and how to solve?

Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

Your $from needs to include an email-address. It can also have their name to, but you need an email-address. You can either have them enter an email-address on the form, or you can just use a 'dummy' email address that always gets sent as the $from.

```
$email = "theuser2323@whatever.com"; // so you could do something like this

$email = $name . '  ' . $lastname . '  ' . 'theuseremailoradummyemail@whatever.com'; // or something like this

$from = $email;

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```